# I cannot boot into bios unless I remove my SSD

Tags: windows-10, bios

Basically what I have said. Windows runs, but I am unable to boot into my BIOS as long as my SSD is plugged in. If I go into the boot menu of windows (Shift click onto restart) no options about bios show up either.

Any ideas what's up with this? It is really weird, but I can't figure out how to fix this

Edit: might be a good idea to provide some specs

PCPartPicker part list: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/DYxMzM

Comment: Your motherboard hasn’t UEFI not BIOS

Comment: @Ramhound Good point, but the issue remains.

Comment: You can **always** access BIOS/UEFI settings with the key assigned for the purpose. Please check your user's manual and/or online documentation. The things is: With an OS installed, any OS, it boots so fast that it makes it hard to press it in time because you have a very small window to do that. Try spamming the key almost simultaneously after powering on.

Comment: @MichaelBay I will try this again, the key is del. Is there any setting I can change to delay the boot up by a second or two?

Comment: Yes, there is  but you have to open the settings to do that. You can disable Fast Boot which is typically enabled by default.